# asyncio: multiplexing messages over single websocket connection

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am using Python 3.6, asyncio and the [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/) library. I am trying to build a client for a websocket-based service which works as follows:

The client can send JSON requests with a custom `id`, a `method` and some `params`. The service will reply with a JSON payload with the same `id` echoed, and `data` as a result of the method call.

I would like to have an abstraction on top of this device that would work sort of like this:

```py
wsc = get_websocket_connection()

async def call_method(method, **params):
    packet = make_json_packet(method, params)
    await wsc.send(packet)
    resp = await wsc.recv()
    return decode_json_packet(resp)

async def working_code():
    separate_request = asyncio.ensure_future(call_method("quux"))

    first_result = await call_method("foo", x=1)
    second_result = await call_method("bar", y=first_result)
    print(second_result)

    return await separate_request
```

Now, I expect the `separate_request` to wait asynchronously while `first_result` and `second_result`s are processed. But I have no guarantee that the `wsc.recv()` call will return the matching response; in fact, I have no guarantees that the service returns the responses in order of requests.

I can use the `id` field to disambiguate the responses. But how can I write the `call_method()` so that it manages the requests internally and resumes the "right" coroutine when the corresponding reply is received?

Answer (score 1):

when I've done this sort of thing before I've tended to split things out into two parts:

1. "sending code" (can be multiple threads) this sets up where responses should go to (i.e. a `dict` of `id`s to functions or `Future`s), then sends the request and blocks for the response
2. "receiving code" (probably one thread per socket) that monitors all inbound traffic and passes responses off to whichever code is interested in the `id`.  this is also a sensible place to handle the socket being closed unexpectedly which should push an exception out as appropriate

this is probably a few hundred lines of code and pretty application specific…